# Quartz Scheduler - Standby Until Following Day

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

How can I make the Quartz Scheduler standby until the following day?

Scenario:
I am searching for a file in a folder every 10 minutes from 3AM-7AM MON-SAT (JOB_A).

If the file is found, I need to search for a second file in the same folder every 10 minutes for the next 3 hours (JOB_B).

If the single file in JOB_A is NOT FOUND on MON, processing should continue on TUE.
If the single file in JOB_A is FOUND on MON, JOB_B should get kicked off but JOB_A should quit for the day and start checking again on TUE at 3AM.

I can kick off JOB_A and it checks appropriately.
When a file is found, I can kick of JOB_B.
However, once I kick off JOB_B, I cannot stop JOB_A for the remainder of the day and start it again the next day.

Any help would be appreciated.

RayK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace JOB_A's trigger with a new one, that uses `startAt(Date)` method so the job doesn't start before the given date.

Here's the code from Quartz's documentation on [how to replace a trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html), combined with the use of `DateBuilder` to get tomorrows's date in a simpler manner:

```
// retrieve the old trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
Trigger newTrigger = tb
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(yourCronExpression))
    .startAt(DateBuilder.tomorrowAt(3,0,0))
    .build();

// tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and put the new one in its place
sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Comment: I believe this would work as a one-time trigger replacement. However, what would happen on WED when I attempted to replace "newTrigger" with "newTrigger"?  I guess I could add a date to the trigger key to make it unique.

Comment: @DropOfGoldenSun Actually you can reuse `oldTrigger`'s key. The code is in the very same Quartz's example page, but I'll update my answer.